# JAXB difference between XsdSchema and XsdSchemaCollection while creating the DefaultWsdl11Definition bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jaxb, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I explore the JAXB and the JAXB2 Maven plugin. I am confused of the bean instantiation.

I have two schemas in `src/main/resources` with the same namespace `www.mycompany.com`. **schemaA.xsd** and **schemaB.xsd** have the same header:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:tns="http://www.mycompany.com"
    targetNamespace="http://www.mycompany.com"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">
```

My `WebServiceConfiguration` extending `WsConfigurerAdapter` defines aside the `ServletRegistrationBean` also the following `XsdSchema(Collection)` beans:

```
// Just a bean with one schema
@Bean
public XsdSchema schema() {
    return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("xsd/schemaA.xsd"));
}

// A bean with both schemas
@Bean
public XsdSchemaCollection schemaCollection() {
    return new XsdSchemaCollection() {

        @Override
        public XsdSchema[] getXsdSchemas() {
            return new XsdSchema[] {
                    new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("xsd/schemaA.xsd")),
                    new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("xsd/schemaB.xsd"))
            };
        }

        @Override
        public XmlValidator createValidator() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
    };
}
```

And the WSDL bean:

```
@Bean(name = "soapWsdl")
public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition(XsdSchema schema, XsdSchemaCollection schemaCollection) {
    DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
    wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("SoapPort");
    wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/service/soap");
    wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace("https://www.mycompany.com");

    // At this point I use just one of the folliwing
    wsdl11Definition.setSchema(schema);
    wsdl11Definition.setSchemaCollection(schemaCollection);

    return wsdl11Definition;
}
```

Using one of these in the bean above:

- `wsdl11Definition.setSchema(schema);`

  If I use only `XsdSchema` defining one schema (regardless whether schemaA or schemaB), everything works, the SOAP Web service is running and WSDL is generated
- `wsdl11Definition.setSchemaCollection(schemaCollection);`

  Now the NPE is thrown although the [`InliningXsdSchemaTypesProvider`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ws/blob/master/spring-ws-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/ws/wsdl/wsdl11/provider/InliningXsdSchemaTypesProvider.java) sets the one schema as the collection with one schema. The error thrown is:

  > 2018-10-05 21:29:28.636  WARN 164968 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'soapWsdl' defined in class path resource [cz/vse/soap/WebServiceConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.DefaultWsdl11Definition]: Factory method 'defaultWsdl11Definition' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
- and a bit below:

  > Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
  >       at org.springframework.xml.xsd.SimpleXsdSchema.getTargetNamespace(SimpleXsdSchema.java:94) ~[spring-xml-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
  >       at com.mycompany.WebServiceConfig.defaultWsdl11Definition(WebServiceConfig.java:66) ~[classes!/:0.0.1]

---

I make the things work with calling the `SimpleXsdSchema::afterPropertiesSet` which is not somehow called upon the bean instantiation. Hard to say what happens. However editing the method like this makes the schemas work together:

```
@Override
public XsdSchema[] getXsdSchemas() {
    SimpleXsdSchema[] schemaArray = new SimpleXsdSchema[] {
            new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("xsd/schemaA.xsd")),
            new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("xsd/schemaB.xsd"))
    };

    for (SimpleXsdSchema schema : schemaArray) {
        try {
            schema.afterPropertiesSet();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException | IOException | SAXException e) { /* ...*/}
    }       
    return schemaArray;
}
```

Does anyone know what happens? Why passing the `XsdSchema` and `XsdSchemaCollection` doesn't behave equally even they are supposed to do according to [`DefaultWsdl11Definition`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/wsdl/wsdl11/DefaultWsdl11Definition.html)?